# MPMoviePlayerController Remove Toggle Button and Minimize

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4.2, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am creating a custom vide player for iPad . I want to remove the following controllers from my Video PLayer (Toggle and Minimize) .

[image: <code>![enter image description here][1]</code>]

[image]